# Hiding the issue history field for users below a certain level

Tags: bug-tracking, mantis

I am currently implementing a new ticket system for my company and have stumbled across Mantis bug tracker which seems like a fairly robust and feature heavy open source bug-tracking system.

However, after browsing their documentation and forums it would appear that guidance in certain areas of the system are somewhat lacking.

We want to avoid our customers from being able to see the priority that has been set to their issue. To do this, we have removed the history fields from the notification emails as well as hiding this field from all pages that an end user can view. The only place that this now appears is in the issue history section at the bottom of the page.

My question is, how can I remove this history section for users below developer level? I would have thought that this would be a configuration option but it would appear not.

I'm happy to tweak the source code but I am now a .Net developer by trade and haven't coded PHP for about 7 years so some guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For hiding the history in emails you need not edit the source code. Just copy the following line to config_inc.php and set the access level.

```
$g_view_history_threshold       = DEVELOPER;
```

Currently, this works only for emails only. But in future it will work in bug view pages also. Check the config_defaults_inc.php for more details.

You can hide the history section for all users by changing the following variable to OFF:

```
g_history_default_visible  = OFF;
```

The default value for all the available configuration is available at **config_defaults_inc.php**, but you should not directly edit there, instead you should copy the variable to **config_inc.php** and then set your own values.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a viable solution. Our developers need to be able to see the history but our clients don't necessarily need access to this section. It's a shame that something which is quite common in bugtracking systems has been overlooked like this in Mantis :-(

Comment: Why do we need to be ashamed? This is a FOSS project and you can contribute in your own ways.

P.S: I'm not an official MantisBT developer.

Comment: Like I said, I'm a .Net developer now and I have actual commercial projects to work on so I don't have time to work on someone else product in a completely different language that I will have to relearn.

Comment: May be you should look for commercial support or other "quite common bug tracking systems"

Comment: We have settled on Mantis because it is free and we cannot waste time looking for another alternative now. Also, it needs to be Open Source as its not something that we really need to spend any money on. I would just build my own in .Net with all the features you would expect but I don't have the time.

Comment: Everyone in the world would like to have everything without spending money or effort. It's a pity. No use in brainstorming :(

Comment: It would also help if their documentation wasn't just TODO on nearly every page!